# Make microwave popcorn in the oven

Tags: oven, popcorn

Have anyone tried making microwave popcorn in a oven? What temperature is preferred? For about how long does it have to be in?

I know I could just rip the bag and pop it a pot but if it's possible to do it in a oven I would try.

Answer (score 15):

I'll come out and say "no, you can't make microwave popcorn in a conventional oven."

For popcorn to pop, the kernel must reach a temperature well above boiling (which builds up steam, causing the kernel to explode). It must do so very quickly, otherwise the moisture will just slowly evaporate out, simply drying the kernel rather than popping it.

Microwave popcorn works because the microwave is primarily heating the kernels directly (because they contain the most water), and quickly. Air poppers don't use the oil, but they do get very hot, and the forced air heats the kernels very fast. And stovetop methods use the heat built up in the oil to heat the kernels quickly. Even fire-popped corn (a fun prospect) relies on fast heat.

Unfortunately, ovens are anything but fast. In the time it would take to heat the kernels, they would just dry out, and possibly start to burn the bag.

If you want popcorn without a microwave, stovetop popcorn is quite easy, and very tasty. I like using a wok, because it's shape is well suited for popcorn (sloped sides keep the kernels in the hot spot, while allowing popped kernels space to expand).

Comment: Might manage something with the use of a baking stone for quicker, more direct heat - though I agree it's likely more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 8):

I did try it:
At 500°F the bag caught fire.

Comment: Seems like a partial answer, could be written more clearly - at the kind of temperature you need to pop corn, the bag catches on fire, so it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't wok.

Comment: This is in disagreement with Asimov's Fahrenheit 451: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451 Paper making techniques have likely changed since 1953.

Comment: Disagreement or agreement?

Comment: Below answers suggest popping popcorn in conventional oven at 450F or 446F (230C) led to popping success and no ignition of paper!

Answer (score 2):

I did this just now but it took too long. Short answer: **not worth the time.** This became a 2 step process. I put the microwave popcorn bag in the oven, baked on about 400 degrees, long enough for the oil to melt. Once the butter melted inside, the bag got a little puffy, while still in the oven. I removed the bag, opened the bag and dumped the contents into a stove top pan, slid out like magic. Popped as usual on top of the stove. It tasted great.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the convection mode thinking it would seal on moisture.  At 500 degrees F the kernels did start to pop.  However, letting the bag stat that hot so long made the plastic melt and the paper seams unglue.  Sort of worked, but the burnt plastic smell was awful and probably chock full o' dioxins.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the bag, scraping out all the popcorn and oil, put in pan with lid, and pop on the stove.

That's really the best way to pop bagged popcorn without the microwave.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:Yes, you can make microwave popcorn in an oven.
I personally tried it and it worked! I hope I helped some pepole with this who don't have a microwave but do have an oven. I used top bottom selection at 230C° for as long as the popcorn keeps popping. If the popping stops for more than 40 seconds then that means that it is done. Easy, medium speed, and delichous! Also put the bag on a tray in the oven and if you want, then put tinfoil under it, but it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Rip open the bag and transfer contents to a makeshift aluminum foil pouch. Seal the pouch except for a small opening for steam to escape. Cook at 450 about 15 min or until popping stops

Comment: Have you done this yourself?